# Continuous function related to group of homeomorphisms acting properly discontinuously must be a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, analysis, covering-spaces

I'm trying to solve the following exercise:

> Let $X$ be a connected space and $G$ a properly discontinuous group of homeomorphisms of $X$. Suppose that a continous map $f: X \to X$ has the following property: for every $x \in X$, there exists $g \in G$ such that $f(x) = gx$. Prove that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

I was able to show $f$ must be injective: if $f(x) = gx = hy = f(y)$ then $x = g^{-1}hy$, and since the action is properly discontinuous, it follows that $g = h$ and hence that $x = y$. I know I also have to show $f$ is surjective, takes open sets to open sets and the inverse image of open sets via $f$ is open, but I've had a hard time with that. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you used connectedness to prove injectivity? Because I believe the best you can prove only with the fact that the action is properly discontinuous is local injectivity. As a counterexample, take $X=\{1,2\}$ with the discrete topology, $G=\{id, \tau\}$ the permutations on $X$ and $f:X\to X$ any constant map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have shown that $f$ is injective, it is enough to show that $f$ is a local homeomorphism and surjective.

Let $x\in X$, and $g$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$. There exists an open subset $U$ containing $x$ such that for every $h\in G$, the intersection $h(U)\cap U$ is not empty implies that $h=e$ the neutral element since the action is properly discontinuous. Write $V=g(U)$. Suppose there exists $h\in G, y\in U$ such that $h(y)\in V$, we have $g^{-1}h(y)\in U$ implies that $g^{-1}h=e$ and $g=h$.

The set $\{y\in X:f(y)=g(x)\}$ is closed, the previous argument shows that it is open since $X$ is connected, it is $X$.

$f^{-1}(V)\cap U=W$ is an open subset. Let $z\in W$, $f(z)=g_z(z), g_z\in G$, since $z\in W\subset U, g_z(z)\in V$, the previous remark implies that $g_z=g$. We deduce that the restriction of $f$ and $g$ to $W$ coincide and $f$ is a local homeomorphism.

Comment: Huh, this kind of argument used to come a bit easier to me before, I guess I'm pretty rusty now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The fact that $\{x\in X: f(x)=g(x)\}=X$, i.e., $f=g$, doesn't already prove that $f$ is a homeomorphism? Also, I believe this argument assumes that $X$ is Hausdorff (which might be negligible, but I just thought it was worth highlighting).